# Multiple instances of SAME service to be accessed from vnet/subnet using Private vs Service Endpoint

Tags: azure, endpoint

When we have a requirement to connect to 2 different storage accounts (SAME service ie Azure Storage / 2 instances) from a VNET/Subnet,
Using-
1.Private Endpoints implies that we need one Private Endpoint for each storage account.
(And single private endpoint can be used across subnets in the vnet) 
2.Service Endpoints implies that a SINGLE Service Endpoint is created for STORAGE SERVICE as a whole and it gets re used for different storage accounts.
(And each subnet needing access to storage accounts would need its own service endpoint)

Would this inference be correct?

[image]

[image]
Regards,
Aditya Garg

Answer (score 1):

What you mentioned is the correct, however, there are more differences and use-case for both these services. One of the [major difference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/private-link-faq#what-is-the-difference-between-service-endpoints-and-private-endpoints-) I would say is

> Private Endpoints grant network access to specific resources behind a given service providing granular segmentation. Traffic can reach the service resource from on-premises without using public endpoints.

> A Service Endpoint remains a publicly routable IP address. A Private Endpoint is a private IP in the address space of the virtual network where the private endpoint is configured.

One should also need to know their limitations

- [Service endpoint limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-service-endpoints-overview#limitations)
- [Private endpoint limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/private-endpoint-overview#limitations)

---

[Some other reference](https://jeffbrown.tech/azure-private-service-endpoint/)